# Can some body explain this function?

Tags: typescript

I have gone through this function while reviewing the code. I didn't understand the parameter passing to the function `valueOf`. Is it instance of the class `PersonData`, if so what is `cc:` meaning?.

```
export class PersonData {

  static valueOf(cc: PersonData): PersonData {
    return new PersonData(
      cc.lastName || null,
      cc.firstName || null,
      cc.gender || null,
      cc.email || null,
      cc.phone || null,
      cc.mobilePhone || null,
      cc.fax || null,
      cc.companyId || null,
      cc.department || null,
      cc.entryDate || null
    );
  }

  private constructor(
    public readonly lastName?: string,
    public readonly firstName?: string,
    public readonly gender?: string,
    public readonly email?: string,
    public readonly phone ?: string,
    public readonly mobilePhone ?: string,
    public readonly fax ?: string,
    public companyId ?: number,
    public department ?: string,
    public  entryDate ?: Date
  ) {}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks interesting and weird :) Is there any usage of "valueOf" in the code?

Comment: This is not related to Angular. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site. cc is your variable name.

Comment: @JustShadow Yes they used 'valueOf' in another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well **cc** is your variable name and PersonData is the object type.

It will return a new PersonData object with values on variable either null or some data.

If cc has lastname='ABC' then the returning object's lastname will be 'ABC' and if cc's lastname=undefined, then the returning object's lastname will be a null. Same to the other variables

So as I could understand, this value of method returns a new object of type PersonData with variables which are not defined converted to null